# MVC - How do I save css changes for user id based on a visited page?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, css, model-view-controller

I want my website to be able to track a users session and remove ".disabled" class when a page has been visited thus 'unlocking' the next page and saving these changes for when a user logs back in. So when one segment is finished, unlock the next.

I have a database tracking pages being visited by ID but can't get my head around how to check the database and apply css changes on page load.

```
.disabled {
pointer-events: none;
cursor: default;
opacity: 0.6; } //Remove this class to unlock content
```

Comment: I think it's a question about DB query. Isn't it?

Comment: it could be, but I dont know if me making a database table is the correct method or maybe there is an easier way.

Comment: Having the session in the DB will help if the user starts their session from one computer, then goes to another computer and tries to continue from there, so I think you're good there. About adjusting the CSS, when the page loads you could make an API call to your backend to get session info and remove the CSS classes accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some possibilities:
assuming you are querying the database in some fashion before you load the page.You could add a property on the on the model that gets populated when you grab the data for the page.Then have the view.cshtml receive the data from model, put in HTML or use razor @model.VisitIDs or something like that.

Another possibility is to write a method in the controller and call that method with ajax after the page loads. For example:

Say you have VisitMe.cshtml, VisitMe.js, VisitMeModel.cs, VisitMeController.cs

The javascript may look like:

```
    // namespace used to organize code not required
    var VisitMeNameSpace = {

    var currentUser = GetCurrentUser();
    var pageName = GetPage();
    var visitMe_GetVisitMeVisitors = "ProjectName/VisitMe/GetVisitMeVisitors";
    var args = {
                page: pagename
               }

    $.ajax({
            url: visitMe_GetVisitMeVisitors,
            type: "GET",
            data: args
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            if (data is good)
                $("selector").removeClass("disabled");
        })
        .fail(function(){
            alert("There was a problem getting visitor IDs for this page");
        });
}// end VisitMeNameSpace 

    // In your C# controller maybe something like 
    public JsonResult GetVisitMeVisitors(string page)
    {
        // whatever you are currently using to query database do that here. We will call this from VisitMe.js
        var visitContainer = new ProjectContainerForVisitMe();
        var visitRecords = (from record in visitContainer.VisitMeTableOrModel where record.page == page select record).ToList();

        return Json(visitRecords, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Please let me know if you need more clarity or if it looks like I misunderstood the question.

Comment: With some adjustments of the code you provided I have got to the solution, thank you